# Functions without statements

Tags: c++

What is the purpose of defining a function without statements?
I have a C++ file with a list of functions defined without statements and they are not used anywhere else in the script. Does this mean they are defined in some other file?

Comment: By statements I believe you meant definitions. There is no point of having declarations without definitions. If are not used anywhere, then what is the use of having their declarations.

Comment: are you talking of *declared* or *defined* functions?

Comment: Are you talking about declaration: `void f();` or definition: `void f() {}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the purpose of defining a function without statements?

This phrase has no meaning. But I suspect you are referring to *function declaration statements* that do not also contain a *definition* (or implementation) of said function.

```
void foo();  // Declaration (may be used as long as definition is linked)
```

---

> Does this mean they are defined in some other file?

And, yes, typically the definitions may be found in other translation units, that are *linked* together to create the final executable.

```
void foo() { // Defining declaration (or just "definition")
   /* ... */
}
```

---

The typical C++ build process should be explained fairly thoroughly in [your C++ book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It is a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) as I now know.

Comment: @Matthew: Not really. "Forward declaration" is a term we tend to use for the similar concept of declaring _types_ (`class myType;`), but non-defining function declarations are very typical and not any sort of party trick, so we don't give them a special name. They're just declarations. Strictly speaking, sure, you could call them "forward declarations" too, but I think that Wikipedia article is highly misleading in suggesting that we actually do.

Comment: And the section about "forward references" is pretty much just plain wrong, by concentrating on lexical ordering where actually, that's not the factor involved. Prefer a C++ book to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

What you have are function definitions.
Probably, those are just stubs which will be implemented during course of the development.

For clearing your ambiguity between declarations and definitions:

**Function declaration:**

```
void doSomething();
```

**Function Definition:**

```
void doSomething()
{

}
```

Typically, Function declarations are in Header(.h or .hpp) files while the definitions reside in the source(.cpp) file.

The declaration of the function acts as an interface for users of the function and they include the header so that they can use the function.
Note that the function prototype and its declaration is decided & fixed during the *design phase* while the actual function implementation is done during the *development phase*.
In parallel development projects usually multiple teams would work on different features which need to exchange data(through functions) amongst themselves, Once the design phase is over the interfaces are exchanged between such teams and both teams then work in parallel to develop their own features, during this phase of development sometimes, just so as to avoid to linking errors, blank functions definitions are used as stubs in projects.

Comment: `Note that the function prototype and its declaration is decided & fixed during the design phase while the actual function implementation is done during the development phase.` That's completely dependent on your development methodology.